# How can I hang up shields in my house?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I've been running around stealing all the different shields of the different holds. They looks pretty sweet and I would like to display them in my house (I currently own the one in Whiterun). I know there are weapon racks for swords and such, but is there something similar for shields? Perhaps in a different house? If not, are there any known plans for modding it in when the creation kit comes out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your house in Whiterun has a shield rack above the bed. You can place two weapons, one on the right and one on the left, and a shield in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

Yup, Skyrim has Shield Racks too!

I know Vlindril Hall, in Markarth, has two, and they work identically to Weapon racks - taking your equipped item and mounting it on the wall.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is take the shield that is already there (usually an iron shield) and place the one you want. You can also put weapons behind the shield too.